Using literal strings in custom date format in iOS Shortcuts app
I’m attempting to create a shortcut that uses the input of a the date like 2024-Wk37. I’ve looked at Unicode Technical Standard #37 and a whole host of examples, but I can’t get this to work without procesing the single quotes as part of the date format.
What I want: 2024-Wk37
What I used: YYYY-‘Wk’w
What I get:  2024-‘29’37



Literal strings in the date format must be quoted with an apostrophe (', Unicode U+0027, aka “single vertical quote”), not with a left single quotation mark (’, Unicode U+2018, aka “typographical quotation mark”). With
YYYY-'Wk'w

you'll get the expected result, for example "2024-Wk37".
Here is the corresponding part from the Unicode #35 Standards: Date Format Patterns (emphasis added):


Literal text, which is output as-is when formatting, and must closely match when parsing. Literal text can include:

Any characters other than A..Z and a..z, including spaces and punctuation.
Any text between single vertical quotes ('xxxx'), which may include A..Z and a..z as literal text.
Two adjacent single vertical quotes (''), which represent a literal single quote, either inside or outside quoted text.





… so a mark not available on my iOS keyboard. How singular. Thanks, you are entirely correct, copying and pasting the right mark worked fine.

@Aquarion: Try pressing and holding the single quote key on the iOS keyboard, then you should see a list of variants to choose from, in particular the vertical apostrophe. (I have a German iOS, so things may be different on your device.)
